# Container view as class member

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, containers, uicontainerview

I have a class and I want it to contain a couple of container views as sub-views.
I want to be able to bring different container views to front according to a specific button click. (i.e first button will bring first container view to front, second button will bring second container view to front).

For this, I need to be able to define the container view as :

```
@IBOutlet var buyContainer: UIView!
```

Unfortunately, I did not understand how this can be done. I tried right-click and dragging the container view to the main view's code, but it just changes the open code to that of the sub-view. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What exactly is `buyContainer`? Is it a simple container view defined in IB? A custom class defined in code? A `.xib` file? If it's a simple view you defined in IB it sounds like you are doing the correct thing.

Comment: try with bringSubview(toFront: yourView) method... may help

Comment: buyContainer should be a container view, defined as a class in xcode